# Link between Scala REPL and a scala class

Tags: scala

I tried to create a scala class like this and saved it as Book.scala

```
class Book(private val title: String) {
  def printTitle(b: Book) {
    println(b.title)
  }
}
```

I then try to use the load the file in REPL and try to use

```
scala> val book = new Book("Beginning Scala")
```

This works fine. But when I try this

```
book.printTitle(new Book("Scala is easy"))
```

I get an error saying that

```
scala> book.printTitle(new Book("Beninning Scala"))
<console>:14: error: value printTitle is not a member of Book
book.printTitle(new Book("Beninning Scala"))
```

But if I create the class in REPL like this

```
scala> class Book (private val title: String) { def printTitle(b: Book) { println (b.title) }
```

I can access the method printTitle. I would like to know why I cannot access a method created in a scala file from repl after loading the file in repl. It will greatly help someone learning Scala.

Comment: This looks weird, I've just tried to reproduce your error but I can't. How do you load your file into the REPL? Are you sure you don't have a definition of it in the classpath that doesn't have the `printTitle` method?

Comment: I tried loading it through :load C:\Desktop\Scala\Book.scala. Am i missing something?

Comment: I cannot reproduce this problem as well. I loaded the file using `:load book.scala`. Try starting the repl in your directory where `Book.scala` is located and use `:load Book.scala` without the full path.

Comment: An alternative way is to give your file on the CLI with the `-i` option, but both ways work for me without a problem. Are you sure you don't have a definition of it in the classpath that doesn't have the printTitle method?

Comment: What is the output of `new Book("")`? You can also see all methods of Book using `new Book("").getClass.getMethods.map(_.getName)`. Like @stefanobaghino mentioned, it looks like another Book class is somewhere in the classpath.

Comment: And using `new Book("").getClass.getPackage.getName` you can get the package name of your class. In your case it should be something like `$line3`. If Book was defined somewhere else, the output will most likely be some package name. Then you know where `Book` comes from.

Comment: Guys, thanks for all your help. I did create a simple "class Book (val title: String)" before. Hence I changed the name of the file to BookP and the class name to BookP and the printTitle method to the sam as well. But I still get the error when I use book.printTitle(new BookP("Scala is easy")). Interestingly when I try new BookP("").getClass.getMethods.map(_.getName), I get only these res10: Array[String] = Array(title, wait, wait, wait, equals, toString, hashCode, getClass, notify, notifyAll) methods. So somewhere this method is missing